# Get previous 15mins / 60 mins data from the current spot time in pine script

Tags: pine-script

how to get previous 15mins / 60 mins data from the current spot time in pine script? for a given symbol. For Ex: if the current spot/close price at 11.00 am, and I need data at 10.45am and 10am respectively. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What timeframe are you going to be using this on?

Answer (score 0):

pine script count on timeframe candle
u can get almost any data by array

previous 1 candle close:

```
close[1]
```

previous 10 ema5:

```
ta.ema(close,5)[10]
```

then base on your timeframe gap to adjust the index number in []